# ¿Como realizar un programa con matriz para buscar un valor y que al final aparezca en el indice?

Tags: java, bucle-for, matriz

````
        ```int [][] matriz = {{0,-10,15,10,5},
        {7,77,-15,20,35},
        {-50,9,65,-45,30}};
    
        
    System.out.print ("Digite un valor a buscar : ");
    int valores = lector.nextInt();
    
    
    
    for(int c = 0; c < matriz.length; c++){
        for(int f = 0; f < matriz[0].length; f++){
            System.out.print (matriz[c][f] + "\t");
````

`**Necesito realizar un programa con una matriz de 3x5, que solicite al usuario un valor para buscar, si el programa encuentra el valor, muestra los indices [f][c] en los cuales se encuentra ese valor. De lo contrario muestra [-1][-1].**`

Números que debo poner en la fila y columna.

{{0,-10,15,10,5},
{7,77,-15,20,35},
{-50,9,65,-45,30}}```

Pantalla final.

`Digite el valor a buscar:20`
`Salidad: [1][3]`

Comment: Cuál es el error en el código?

Comment: No tiene error, solo necesito encontrar el valor en el indice.

Comment: Puedes verificar con un `if` y recorriendo la matriz en un `for` como ya lo tienes.

Comment: Ok gracias, voy a revisar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Código corregido.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        int [][] matriz = {{0,-10,15,10,5},
        {7,77,-15,20,35},
        {-50,9,65,-45,30}};


        System.out.print("Digite un valor a buscar : ");
        int valores = lector.nextInt();

        // arreglo para guardar las posicion
        // donde se encuentra el elemento
        // inicializado en -1 en caso no se encuentra
        int[] posicion = new int[] {
            -1, -1
        };

        for (int c = 0; c < matriz.length; c++) {
            // acceder a matriz[c] no usar 0 porque los arreglos
            // internos podrían tener una longitud diferente
            for (int f = 0; f < matriz[c].length; f++) {
                if (matriz[c][f] == valores) {
                    // si se encuentra el valor
                    // guardar su posicion
                    // y terminar la ejecución
                    posicion = new int[]{ c, f};
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // imprimir la posicion
        System.out.print("Salida: " + Arrays.toString(posicion));
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente me sirvió mucho gracias.